# Email button (emailauthor.jsp) results in "The page you submitted was invalid for your session"

Tags: email, custom-button

About 1 month ago my email button stopped working.  Now pressing my 'auto-email' button gives me the email template page with the error

> "The page you submitted was invalid for your session. Please click
>   Save again to confirm your change."

If I click '**Send**' on this page the email gets sent normally.

I am not aware of anything changing in the last month that may have caused this to stop working.  I have played around with the email button javascript but have not found a solution.

The button code is:

```
location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Matter__c.Id}&p3_lkid={!Matter__c.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Matter__c.OwnerEmail}&template_id=00X90000000f1yQ&p24=myemail@mycompany.com.au&p5=&save=1');
```

I have tried removing most tags and just leaving the required tags and changing Matter__c.Id with Account.Id but had no luck.

Any help appreciated.